How to validate that a multi-class prediction of an XGBoost model matches a known correct output (comparing two np.arrays to each other)
Can someone suggest the best way to validate that a multi-class model prediction (a numpy.array) matches a known expected output?
Using the popular Iris dataset, I've built a simple XGBoost model.  I'm trying to get a test working, which is set up something like this:
import xgboost as xgb
import numpy as np

pred_test = xgb.DMatrix([[5.1, 3.5, 1.4, 0.2]
                         , [4.9, 3. , 1.4, 0.2]
                         , [4.7, 3.2, 1.3, 0.2]])

preds = xgb_model.predict(pred_test)
print(type(preds)) # <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
one_prediction = preds[0]

# one_prediction looks like: array([0.990855  , 0.00562044, 0.00352454], dtype=float32)

# I want to compare one_prediction to an expected output

expected_output = np.array([0.990855, 0.00562044, 0.00352454], dtype=np.float32)
expected_output == one_prediction # Result: array([ True,  True, False])


The last line illustrates my problem.  I would expect the one_prediction to exactly match expected_output, but the boolean test fails for 1 out of 3 values.  Thanks for the help!
